# referencing local resources from assets in a static html

Tags: android

I have a webview in my activity and loaded contents for webview by following:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/description.html");
```

In description.html i have a reference for another html file located in the same place by following:

```
<a href='file:///android_asset/uml.html'>see UML diagram</a>
```

This was working absolutely fine in emulator but when i run it on my Galaxy S mobile, hyperlink does not work fine. Kindly help me. Is there any permission i am missing or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the Uses_Internet permission?  Even though you are not accessing the internet, to use a webview still requires Internet Permission. I think.

Comment: I tested it on G1 and it is working fine there but not working in Galaxy S i9000.